# What is Accessory protocol string (com.apple.blabla ???) of Apple Watch

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, apple-watch, wcsession, eaaccessory

I am trying to build application for iOS that from the very beginning knows which Apple Watch is currently paired and connected to iPhone. I have two Apple Watches that are currently paired and connected to iPhone but only one (as it should be) selected in 'Watch' application.
I can check that iPhone has paired Apple Watch with WCSession.paired, also I can list all the bluetooth devices that might connect to iPhone with their UDID's but I need to know for certain which one (containing UDID) paired and connected In exact moment.
CoreBluetooth framework does not provide opportunity to know which one is connected from the beginning, it gives ability to connect device.
So, I seek info about accessory string of Apple Watch to use with EAAccessoryManager. Any help will be appreciated.